# How to measure webpage loading time from command line

Tags: javascript, performance, curl, browser

There is an internal webpage, which has embedded java script code. When the page is opened in browser, it takes time to load . This is due to the execution time of js libraries calls. For observability/metrics purpose I need to measure the loading time of this page from linux/mac command line. When I use   `time curl "webpage url"`  it dumps the html source but does not execute the js code. How could I make to run the js code to know loading time of the page?

Appreciate any pointers in getting the page loading time from command line. TIA.

Comment: To get actual page load times you will need to mimic the browser. Checkout Selenium webdriver

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK (and as someone mentioned in the comment section) it's not possible to do it clearly without any browser which actually executes JS

but there are few possible workarounds:

1. use headless browsers/selenium/etc.
2. connect to API's (e.g. Google PageSpeed Insights https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started), so you will actually work with third party service to retrieve result

Simplified schema:
Command line -> ping API of page speed measurement service -> third-party service renders page, measures performance -> get your results back to you

You might actually call it from CURL, like this

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https://developers.google.com&key=yourAPIKey
```